# Using Puppet to remove SSH keys not explicitly allowed

Tags: ssh, puppet

I'm using puppet to distribute SSH keys, like so:

```
ssh_authorized_key { "alice@foo.com":
   ensure => present,
   key => 'xxxx',
   type => 'ssh-rsa',
   user => 'deploy',
}
```

The ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file ends up containing a mix of keys from multiple classes, which is the desired result.  However, if a key is manually added to $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys, Puppet will leave it in place.  Is there a way to always remove any key that has not been explicitly defined in a manifest?

I have puppet version 2.7.1.

Comment: I was thinking about using exported resources to get a copy of all my authorized_keys files into a central location.  Then I could run scripts to find unusual keys, and either add them to puppet or add a resource to remove them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with Puppet 3.6 it is now possible to [purge unmanaged SSH authorized keys](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/release_notes.html#feature-purging-unmanaged-ssh-authorized-keys) via the `user` type. For example,

```
user { 'nick':
  ensure         => present,
  purge_ssh_keys => true,
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Instead of using `ssh_authorized_key` resources, I decided to define an `authorized_keys` resource, which takes a list of all SSH keys for a single user. The define looks like this:

```
define authorized_keys ($sshkeys, $ensure = "present", $home = '') {
    # This line allows default homedir based on $title variable.
    # If $home is empty, the default is used.
    $homedir = $home ? {'' => "/home/${title}", default => $home}
    file {
        "${homedir}/.ssh":
            ensure  => "directory",
            owner   => $title,
            group   => $title,
            mode    => 700,
            require => User[$title];
        "${homedir}/.ssh/authorized_keys":
            ensure  => $ensure,
            owner   => $ensure ? {'present' => $title, default => undef },
            group   => $ensure ? {'present' => $title, default => undef },
            mode    => 600,
            require => File["${homedir}/.ssh"],
            content => template("authorized_keys.erb");
    }
}
```

`$ssh_keys` parameter takes all necessary keys as a list. The `authorized_keys.erb` template looks like this:

```
# NOTICE: This file is autogenerated by Puppet and should not be modified
<% sshkeys.each do |key| -%>
<%= key %>
<% end -%>
```

#### Usage

```
user {'mikko':
    ...
}
authorized_keys {'mikko':
    sshkeys => [
        'ssh-rsa XXXXXXYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZ mikko@domain.tld',
        'ssh-rsa XXXXXXZZZZZZZZZHHHHHHHHH mikko@other-host.tld',
    ],
}
```

Adding SSH keys conditionally (for example in different classes) is also easy, thanks to Puppet's `+>` operator:

```
Authorized_keys <| title == 'mikko' |> {
    sshkeys +> 'ssh-rsa ASDFASDFASDFASDF mikko@somewhere-else.tld'
}
```

With this method, the user will never have keys that are not explicitly specified in the Puppet configuration. The key string is used in authorized_keys just as it is, so adding options and restrictions is trivial.

I would be happy to hear if others have used this method successfully!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this using the *resources* metatype. E.G.

```
resources { 'ssh_authorized_key': noop => true, purge => true, }
```

Setting `noop => true,` prevents the removal from taking place. Instead, puppet will report what would be removed. If it is what you want, remove the *noop* statement.

The ideal syntax for performing operations on unmanaged resources is [under discussion](http://dxul.puppetlabs.com/issues/7600).

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, this answer does not work.

Comment: This sound like just what I'm looking for.  When I add this line, puppet produces this error:  `puppet-agent[9895]: (/Stage[main]//Resources[ssh_authorized_key]) Failed to generate additional resources using 'generate': Attribute 'user' or 'target' is mandatory.`  I tried adding a user, and then it says `Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid parameter user `.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's probably worth asking on http://groups.google.com/group/puppet-users

Comment: I'm really unclear why this is the accepted answer: as per Puppet Labs, this doesn't work and hasn't: http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/1917 .  OP, did it work for you?

Comment: No, I didn't try it, I just expected it to behave like it did for other resources (e.g. hosts, nagios types). Looks like you're right and it does not work for ssh keys yet- http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/1581

Answer (score 1):

On Puppet Forge a module has been published under the Apache License, Version 2.0 that offers this ability.

It relies on Puppet concat instead of templates though.

https://github.com/nightfly19/puppet-ssh_keys/tree/master/manifests

Instead of passing an array of keys as a parameter you define separate entries for each key.

Different approach from Mikko's, but same net result.

Comment: https://forge.puppetlabs.com/nightfly/ssh_keys  is the Puppet Forge link.